# How to play videos in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-videoview

I'm beginner on Android studio.

I want to play videos in android studio?
How can I play videos without using raw or assets folder as I have a lot of video files?
Storing videos in raw package is increasing my Android studio Project size.
Is there any other way I can play videos?

Answer (score 0):

I supose you are doing it like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Lq3HyBCuAA), but you shold not if you are gonna put more than one or two videos. The first option is using a [WebView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcfcG31AgyE), and the second option wich i strongly recommend is using a [VideoView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVSoDMeMRy0). Hope this helps. :)